# RailsTutorial Chp 3 (Section 3.2.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Here's the issue from Section 3.2.2 Adding a page:

They intentionally left out creating the About page (in Section 3.1.2) so as to teach me how to use TDD to guide me through the development process. I progressed through adding code to the spec tests, route, and StaticPages controller (Listings 3.13, 3.14 and 3.15 with all the steps in between).

However when I came to the step right before Listing 3.16 I had to tilt my head. Here's the text: "To solve this issue, we add the about view. This involves creating a new file called about.html.erb in the app/views/static_pages directory with the contents shown in Listing 3.16."

My question is how do I "add the about view and create a new file called about.html.erb in the app/views/static_pages directory"? I added the about action to my StaticPages controller but that doesn't do anything by virtue of the test $ bundle exec rspec... that says i'm missing a "template" or view. Yet the next step "involves creating a new file called about.html.erb" with no direction on how.

The last time I remember creating static page files was Section 3.1.2 using $ rails generate controller StaticPages home help --no-test-framework where it created home.html.erb and help.html.erb. So I ran $ rails generate controller StaticPages about --no-test-framework. It asked if I wanted to overwrite the file app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb and I said no; yet, it did create my about.html.erb file.

I got the result I needed but it didn't feel right. Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They mean to just create the file using your chosen text editor.

```
#Here is how with nano
nano app/views/static_pages/about.html
Type in some text
CTRL-O to Save

#Here is how with vi

vi app/views/static_pages/about.html
i for insert mode
Type in some text
ESC :wq  to Save


#If you just want to create an empty file
touch app/views/static_pages/about.html
```

Comment: How would I do it in Sublime Text 2?

Comment: subl app/views/static_pages/about.html

Comment: Huh. Wow. Thanks Shawn. If you haven't noticed yet, I'm a complete noob. I appreciate your help.